# Related questions on sidebar missing

Tags: bug, status-completed, questions, related-questions

I noticed yesterday in a couple of questions and today in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/920483/test-the-convergence-of-the-series-sum-sin-pi-sqrt52n) one that, at least on my screen, the *related questions* are missing.

Why is this? Why does it only happen sometimes? Can I do it in such way that I can see it every time?

Comment: I suppose that the system didn't find anything related; or that the sidebar has taken a quick sidebar and it will be back in the next episode of "Quests for Glory", err, I mean "Math S-E".

Comment: Seeing that no Related sidebars were generated since my answer, I'm retagging as a bug.

Comment: ... and now the problem went away. Related sidebar is shown for all questions expect the very new ones (posted within a few minutes).

Comment: @Haney: How is this a non-repro? The answer below indicates that this is "automatically solved" for sufficiently old questions, so the linked question will have a "Related" sidebar. Instead take a look at the newest question posted at time of seeing this comment. I still see the problem occurring (and it's an annoying one, since the "Related" bar often includes a good source for duplicates).

Comment: @Haney As of now, none of the questions posted since September 7 have the Related sidebar. Specifically, [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/922683/) and all posted since then.

Comment: I can confirm Friday's predecessor's observation. And I can't say that I've entered the question linked in his question before, so it's definitely not a caching issue in this aspect.

Comment: Taking a look now, this is *not* working as expected and I was mistaken.

Answer (score 8):

Well this was fun; basically, our background processing for these... stopped background processing. It looks like it is related to some `async` changes that were introduced (and possibly the dreaded sync-context deadlock that people using .NET `Task`s may be aware of). So; we have a bit of a backlog to churn through, and it is going to take some time to catch up and be as responsive as we would like. To help with this, I have changed this code to scale out over more of our background processing servers (when there wasn't a backlog, it was working fine on a "one server wins and does everything" basis; with a backlog, it needs more concurrency). I'll keep an eye on it - hopefully it will have caught up soon!

Answer (score 6):

It appears that the Related sidebar is slow to be built at the moment. To verify:

1. [Sort questions by newest](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest)
2. Check that none of questions on the first page have Related sidebar.
3. Check that earlier questions, starting from about the middle of page 2, have Related sidebar. Specifically, [Prove that $V$ is a complete space](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/920405/) is the most recent  question with the Related sidebar.

Possible cause: search engine tubes are clogged, which happened earlier:  [Why don't I see the "related questions" column?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/161042/)

Comment: Informative as always. I confirmed your conjecture.

Comment: It was a system hiccup that should be working as intended now.

Comment: @JonasMeyer I am mistaken, this is clearly *not* working as intended.